# How to assign the null/nil value to ballerina package level variable

Tags: ballerina

Is there any way to define the variable in package level(scope is package not method) and not to initialise value for that and assign the value dynamically?

Comment: AFAIK all Ballerina variables have to be initialized. You might be looking for an [optional type](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/optional-type.html). Also the correct name for a value that indicates an absence of a value is `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
int? i = ();

public function main() {
   i = 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to create a package variable(say type of time:Time and assign it to null first and assign value later? How can I do that? when I tried to assign value to type time:Time?, it says "type ballerina/time:Time?" does not support field access?

Comment: @Mayuran `time:Time? t = ();` works for me as expected. Please see [time:Time](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time/index.html) for examples how to use `Time`.